# send Ajax call and form_tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a problem with my ajax call in rails when I use form_tag or form_for

my form_tag looks like:

```
` <%= form_tag(type_name_Tous_path, :method => "get") do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :key,params[:key]" %>
        <%= text_field_tag :lieu,params[:lieu]" %>
        <%= select_tag :nom, options_from_collection_for_select(TypeName.all, :id, :nom, params[:nom]),id:"select_categori"%></span>
        <button id="input_btn"><%= submit_tag "Chercher"%></button>
        <ul id="sous_select">
          <% @tag %>
        </ul>
    <% end %>`
```

my ajax call looks like:

```
 ` $(function(){
      $(".selectable").selectable({
          selected: function(event, ui){
              var selected=$("li[class$='ui-selected']").val();
              $('#input_btn').click(function(){
                  alert(selected);
                  if(selected != null){
                      $.ajax({
                          url:'/type_name/Tous',
                          type:'Get',
                          data:{my_ta:selected},
                          success:function(data){
                              alert(data)
                          },
                          error:function(data){
                              alert("erreur"+data)
                          }
                      })
                  }else{
                      console.log('pas de selection proposé')
                  }})}});});`
```

And in my controller when I make a puts "ok ok #{params[:my_ta]}" I have two answers , the first one , with the good answer exemple "ok ok 9" and after the second answer is like "ok ok" , it's because I call twice type_name route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **Rails can help you with this!**

If you use `form_with` instead of your `form_tag`, Rails will automatically assume that your form will be using an ajax call.

So now you will have a corresponding action in your controller where you're pointing your route to have it.
For example, if your route were something like this:

```
#routes.rb
...
# Bad practice to use capital letters in snake case, 
# only_small_letters_will_do
get 'type_name' => 'your_controller#type_name', as: "type_name_tous"
```

Now your action `type_name` will have your forms params on submit.

I would recommend putting a `byebug` in your new `type_name` action and do a  submit to see how your params are doing :)

The values are there, so you don't have to do a

```
var selected=$("li[class$='ui-selected']").val();
```

[Read more about handling javascript in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I try your advices but it doesn't work do you have an other option please ?

Comment: Is anything working?
Can you connect your route to the controller?
And you need to change from tags to (as an example) f.text_field. Do you know how to do that?